# creating a create/edit view/action with SelectList in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

the basic idea is that you have some class that has a reference type property, something like this

```
public class Person 
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public Country HomeCountry { get; set; }
}

public class Country 
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

now if you need to **create a view to edit Person's data** you don't have any problems with Name or Id, but you do have with Country;

at the moment i have two basic solutions

**nr1:** in the action method i put
 `ViewData["Countries"] = countryService.GetAll();`
and use it in the view with something like this 
`SelectList(ViewData["Countries"], Country.Id`

and i'm gonna have [the post action] Create(Country country)

**nr2:** Create a PersonDto or PersonViewModel (same thing i guess)

here i'm gonna have Create(CountryVieModel countryViewModel) and no usage of ViewData

```
 public class PersonViewModel
     {
     Person Person { get; set; }
     public SelectList Countries { get; private set; }


     public PersonViewModel(Person person) 
     {
     Person = person;
     var countryService = container.Resolve<CountryService>();
     Countries = new SelectList(countryService.GetAll(),Person.Country);
     }

   }
```

but I feel like there should some way better than these two

***anybody knows the best way to do this ?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, nr2 is the best.

Comment: actually I was thinking that there should be something better than these two; in nr2 i make a call to the database inside the ViewModel

Comment: I prefer to do this, but most others dont. This is another discussion which might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1593406/who-has-the-responsibilty-of-loading-data/1594300#1594300